# C# coordinate keyed dictionary

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, coordinate

I have a class `Room`, and a class `World`. Currently, I have a

```
    Dictionary<Point, Room> world;
```

which I store `Room`s in like so:

```
    world.Add(new Point(0,0), new Room());
```

But when I try to access it, it returns null:

```
    world.Get(new Point(0,0));
```

I understand the reason why this is happening. But my question is: Does anybody know a better way of doing this?

Comment: What is the reason (design reason) that you are using a Dictionary<>?

Comment: vs. an array? I'm making this for a text based game that contains "rooms", and if you go into a room thats nonexistant, it lets you create the room. It would be a pain in the neck to use an Array, with all the resizing and stuff, so I went with a Dictionary

Comment: Is "Point" your class?  If not, what "Point" class/struct are you using?

Comment: I was using my own Point class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That should work fine, provided your `Point` implementation implements `GetHashCode` and `Equals` properly.

For example, the following works perfectly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;

class Room
{
    public int X
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

struct Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<Point, Room> world = new Dictionary<Point, Room>();

        world.Add(new Point(0, 0), new Room() { X = 0 });
        world.Add(new Point(2, 3), new Room() { X = 2 });

        Room room = world[new Point(2, 3)];

        Console.WriteLine(room.X);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This is using System.Drawing.Point, which implements `GetHashCode` properly.  (It prints "2", as expected.)

I suspect the problem is your implementation of `Point`.  Make sure it implements `Equals` and `GetHashCode` correctly, or (better yet) use a version of Point included in the framework.

Comment: Using `System.Windows.Point` instead of my own class worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins: The problem is that a class/struct must implement Equals + GetHashCode properly if you want to use it as a Key in a dictionary...

Answer (score 1):

You can [provide your own IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx) when you instantiate the dictionary:

```
public Dictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
```

This works even if you can't modify the original TKey class.

Comment: does this mean that the dictionary will work in O(n), since there is no more hashing?